# php mysqli: configuring issues

Tags: php, apache, mysqli, configure, mysql

I am currently running an Apache 2.4 server with PHP 5.5.1, and it is connected to Django via mod_wsgi (in case that matters).  This is all running on Oracle Linux.  In this set-up, I am trying to use mysqli and the method `mysqli_connect`.  However, I am facing issues with my mysqli set-up.  I have used the following website: [MySQLi Setup](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/apis-php-mysqli.setup.html).  However, even after running `./configure --with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysqlconfig` and `./configure --with-mysqli`, I still do not see a mysqli section in my phpinfo() test site.  I have run make and make install after both and it has worked fine.

Furthermore, when I try the following command `./configure --with-mysql=/usr/bin/mysql_config --with-mysqli=mysqlnd`, I get the following error: `configure: error: Cannot find MySQL header files under /usr/bin/mysql_config. Note that the MySQL client library is not bundled anymore!`

On top of this, I have uncommented the `extension=php_mysqli.dll` line.

Right now, I have an idea of what I need to do, which is to get ahold of the MySQL client library and allow access to it by php.  However, I am unsure of how to do this, and many of the questions + answers I have found have not worked.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: i'm not an expert but sounds like mysqli is PHP and django  & mod_wsgi is Python

Comment: Oh, yeah.  I added that information for the sake of clarification in case it might have an effect, but maybe I'll comment that part out.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean.  I thought MySQLi is an extension for PHP, whereas MySQL is the database itself.  Are you saying that I shouldn't have the configuration option `--with-mysql=/usr/bin/mysql_config` included?

Comment: forgot what i said...was an error